# Obtener los datos de todos los nodos de un usuario en Firebase y mostrarlos en un textView

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase

Me gustaría saber como acomodar mi codigo o cual es la falla que tengo para poder obtener los datos de todos los nodos de un usuario y mostrarlos en un TextView. Actualmente puedo mostrar un solo nodo con OrderByChild después de Users, pero cuando quiero mostrar todos los nodos, no me muestra nada solamente el texto que tiene definido el TextView. 
Les agradecería mucho el que me puedan ayudar

```
public class PerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private  TextView mTextViewData;
private TextView mTextViewData2;
private  TextView mTextViewData3;
private TextView mTextViewData5;
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
.getInstance().getReference();
Query mDatabase = mDatabaseReference.child("Users")
.child("zBJ8IhRvzVOlAU9Y6ubI8nXb0H33").child("apellidomaterno")
.child("apellidopaterno").child("nombre").child("telefono");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTextViewData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewData);
    mTextViewData2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    mTextViewData3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mTextViewData5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

 } 
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////ONNCREATE

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String apellidomaterno = dataSnapshot
                .child("apellidomaterno").getValue(String.class);
                mTextViewData3.setText(apellidomaterno);
                String apellidopaterno = dataSnapshot
                .child("apellidopaterno").getValue(String.class);
                mTextViewData2.setText(apellidopaterno);
                String nombre = dataSnapshot
                .child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
                mTextViewData.setText(nombre);
                String telefono = dataSnapshot
                .child("telefono").getValue(String.class);
                mTextViewData5.setText(telefono);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError
             .getCode());
        }
    });
```

[image: Adjunto imagen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La query solo deberia ser al nodo padre de los datos

```
Query mDatabase = mDatabaseReference.child("Users")
.child("zBJ8IhRvzVOlAU9Y6ubI8nXb0H33");
```

Ya que con esa referencia vas a poder acceder a cada valor del usuario.

Recorda guardar los valores en firebase con nombres sin espacios, por ejemplo apellido_paterno , para que luego lo puedas obtener desde tu cliente de la siguiente forma

```
String apellidomaterno = dataSnapshot
                .child("apellido_materno").getValue(String.class);
```

Para mostrar todos los nodos deberias cambiar la query tambien

```
Query mDatabase = mDatabaseReference.child("Users");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
  @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String apellidomaterno = data.child("apellidomaterno").getValue(String.class);
                String apellidopaterno = data.child("apellidopaterno").getValue(String.class);
                String nombre = data.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
                String telefono = data.child("telefono").getValue(String.class);
               Log.d("ApellidoMaterno:",apellidomaterno);
               Log.d("ApellidoPaterno:",apellidopaterno);
               Log.d("Nombre:",nombre);
               Log.d("Telefono:",telefono);

    }
  }
      @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
   });
```

De esta forma es recomendable que uses un Log en vez de un TextView, ya que el for solo te va a mostrar el valor del ultimo elemento encontrado en la repeticion dentro del textview.

Comment: @GastónSantillén Gracias, funciono